# Is there a more efficient way to generate random binomial numbers in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

Currently my model is using the following snippet for random binomial number generation, it's effectively the lynchpin that makes the whole thing work and is called the most frequently:

```
to-report random-binomial [n p]
  report sum n-values n [ifelse-value (p > random-float 1) [1] [0]] 
end
```

However, this function doesn't run very quickly if n becomes very large (e.g. 10,000,000). Based on an old thread I'm trying a possibly more efficient solution:

```
to-report random-binomial [n p]
  report length filter [i -> i < p] n-values n [random-float 1]
end
```

Naturally due to how often this can be called, any small slowdowns will massively snowball into the rest of the model. Does anyone know of a better way to perform this kind of calculation, especially when n becomes stupidly big?

Comment: it's always going to be expensive to do something a stupidly big number of times. Is it critical to use the exact binomial distribution in your application? Most would switch to the normal distribution at much lower sample sizes than 10 million unless your probability of success is extremely small

Comment: We've been mulling over the problem in the the lab and came to a similar conclusion, normal distribution or just using p as a proportion as-is may be the only way to effectively solve this.

Comment: i expect this is not really a NetLogo issue, but if you think NetLogo is less efficient at stupidly large numbers of random draws than (say) R, you could use the R extension to do the binomial draws. However, I just did a trial of 100 million at 50% and any difference was small between your NetLogo code and `sum(rbinom(100000000, 1,.5))` in R so the overhead of the R extension is likely not worth it

Answer (score 3):

In general the answer to questions like this (how to efficiently implement a well-known function) is to look in the numerical methods literature for a tried and true algorithm. The classic reference used to be "Numerical recipes in C". I'm sure a little searching will find a method (e.g., when and how to use the normal distribution as an approximation).